# syntax of sigchld and its declaration

Tags: c, sigchld

On compiling my C program for implementing multiple client server chat program using UDP ,i got some errors..I was able to correct some of them, but cannot do with some others.. 
They are....:

1) unknown type name  sig_atomic_t

2) storage size of sigchild_action isn't known

3) SIGCHLD undeclared (first use in this function)

4) SIGUSR2 undeclared (first use in this function)

I dont know how to solve this errors...I tried a lot, but was not able to find anywhere the syntax of sigchild....n know about how to declare it...Please do help me.....

Comment: Show us some code and the errors and check if you're including `signal.h`.

Answer (score 11):

What about including the appropriate header:

```
#include <signal.h>
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, I thought that clone-related signals are included by sched.h

Comment: @Bulwersator No worries.